# Using 2-sided log-rank test for the data (burn) from KMsurv package

Tags: r

I'm trying to run a 2 sided, log-rank test for testing the hypothesis for T3 and Z1 in the data (burn).,(KMsurv).

Here is the used code:

```
library(KMsurv)
data()
data(burn)
burn

library(survival)
KM.fit<-survfit(Surv(T3,Z1)~1,data=burn)
summary(KM.fit)
plot(KM.fit, lty=1:2, lwd=2, col=c("black", "blue"))
legend(5, 0.4, c("group 1: surgically", "group 2: percutaneously"), lty=1:2, lwd=c(2,2), col=c("black", "blue"))

logrank<-survdiff(Surv(T3, Z1)~Treatment, data=burn)
logrank$obs[1]
logrank$exp[1]
logrank$var[1,1]
```

the error message is:
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Treatment' not found

What should I ues instead of "Treatment" in order to compare the 2 patients?
Is there something else wrong in the code?

Comment: You get this error because there is no column named "Treatment" in your dataset "burn"

Comment: Do you have any suggestion about what I should replace Treatment with?

Comment: It's all depend of what is the hypothesis you are testing and what are representing each variables of data `burn`. As there is no clear designation of in their names, it's hard to know what they are representing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(survival)
```

The following is incorrect:

```
KM.fit<-survfit(Surv(T3,Z1)~1,data=burn)
```

You probably want:

```
KM.fit <- survfit(Surv(T3, D3)~1, data=burn)
```

This is overall survival from straphylocous aureaus infection. See the help page for `Surv` for details on how to construct this object. To plot the survival curve:

```
plot(KM.fit, lwd=2)
```

This gives Kaplan-Meier survival curve for the whole group with 95% confidence interval.

To test for a Treatment effect (Z1: bathing vs body cleansing), you then add Z1 to the right-hand side of the formula:

```
KM.fit.Z1 <- survfit(Surv(T3,D3)~Z1, data=burn)
KM.fit.Z1

cols <- c("black", "blue")
plot(KM.fit.Z1, lwd=2, lty=1:2, col=cols)
legend(5, 0.3, c("group 1: Bathing", "group 2: bodily cleansing"), 
       lty=1:2, lwd=c(2,2), col=cols)
```

And the test:

```
survdiff(Surv(T3, D3)~Z1, data=burn)
```

The help page of `burn` explains the variables:

> Z1 Treatment: 0-routine bathing 1-Body cleansing
>
> Z2 Gender (0=male 1=female)
>
> Z3 Race: 0=nonwhite 1=white
>
> T3 Time to straphylocous aureaus infection or on study time
>
> D3 Straphylocous aureaus infection: 1=yes 0=no

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I'm looking for.                                                                                I'm also trying to use Gehan’s test and Tarone and Ware weights.                                    When using the code `(gehan.test(T3, D3, Z1) ` , I got an error message says gehan.test not found.                                                                                                                      Regarding to Tarone and Ware, what is the appropriate code that could be used?                         A little clarification would be appreciated.